# RE: vue-bootstrap-typeahead API (serializer)

Tags: vue.js, typeahead, serialization

I'm making a vue application that makes use of [vue-bootstrap-typeahead](https://alexurquhart.github.io/vue-bootstrap-typeahead/#/reference) . There's a part in its API reference that makes use of `serializer`, particularly for dropdown suggestion coming from an external resource. Could someone explain this to me a little further? Been looking for answers online, but I couldn't seem to get it to work. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
<template>
   <div class="container">
      <vue-bootstrap-typeahead
        v-model="query"
        placeholder="search for someone"
        :serializer="input => input"
        :data="names"                      
       />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
     return {
     query: '',
     selectedUser: null,
     names: []
    }
   }
  },

  watch: {
   query(newQuery) {
   axios.get(`api/participant?fName=${newQuery}`)
    .then((res) => {
      this.users = res.data.items
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

when I'm using a pre-defined array of data for suggestions, it works. But when trying to query from a resource, it doesn't work. Does any of you have any prior experiences with this package before? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  This code looks like the example on the vue-bootstrap docs.  Where is **your** code so that we can try to find the issue that you are running into?

Comment: Actually, I've literally tried to copy-paste the exact same code from the examples into my project, but it doesn't seem to work.. I mean, the dropdown suggestions do not appear when I'm querying from an external resource. The value for `serializer` is the one I don't really understand. According to the reference, the default value is `input => input`. In one example provided, the value is `s => s.item`. And in the other one, `item => item.login`. I'm guessing, it has something to do wigh the api resource you're fetching your data from? I'm not really sure. Nothing worked for me..

Comment: In my case, I'm just querying the data from a local database.

Answer (score 0):

:serializer="input => input" means that you api return some array of objects right? and then you just show the element as to like toString(), this way your api should return an array of string.
If the api return for example: [{Id:1, Desc: "One"}, {Id:2, Desc:"Two"}] you should put there :serializer="input => input.Desc"